# Indirect Population of Textarea in HTML Form Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on an "Update User Data" form, which should reflect the initially entered information stored in the database into the textarea, and can be changed if the user wishes to. While I'm doing so, I have a concern - is directly writing `value = <?php //some code ?>` the safest bet?

I was trying to invoke a function to place my PHP code in that instead, but apparently it's just displaying the function's name.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<div>Date of Birth: </div>
    <input id="dob" type="date" onFocus="emptyElement('status')" value="reflect_data('dob');">
```

where the function reflect_data is defined as -

```
function reflect_data(elem) {
//query and some code to access the data and store into $member

if (elem == "dob") {
    echo $member['DOB'];
    exit();
}
```

NOTE : A newbie to PHP, any advice would be welcome. Thanks. :)

Comment: Once the browser receives the web page, php has long forgotten about the page that you are seeing. value = <?php //some code ?> is about the only way to show data immediately unless you want to go the Ajax route.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Thanks for the technical explanation, @jeff, makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You use php code in a JS function. That won't work that way and is impractical. Simple:

```
<input id="dob" type="date" onFocus="emptyElement('status')" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($member['DOB']); ?>">
```

is the best solution.